# Outlook 2010 PST Encryption Algoirthm

Tags: encryption, outlook, outlook-2010

What algorithm does Outlook 2010 use for it it's pst encryption?

I am hoping it is AES 128 or 256....

Cheers

Comment: This isn't really an answer as such, so I won't post it as one. The PST file format is now openly documented and can be downloaded from [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff385210%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PSTs are not encrypted the way you would think.  They do not use a standard encryption scheme, but a custom one.  From the PST specification.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff385210%28office.12%29.aspx

> **4.1   Strength of Encoded PST Data Blocks**
>
> This protocol uses two keyless cipher
>   algorithms to encode the data blocks
>   in the PST. These algorithms only
>   provide data obfuscation and can be
>   conveniently decoded once the exact
>   encoding algorithm is understood.
>
> Moreover, only end-user data blocks
>   are encoded in the PST. All the other
>   infrastructure  information, including
>   the header, allocation metadata pages
>   and BTree pages are stored without
>   obfuscation.
>
> In summary, the strength of the
>   encoded PST data blocks provides no
>   additional security beyond data
>   obfuscation.
>
> **4.2   Strength of PST Password**
>
> The PST Password, which is stored as a
>   property value in the Message store,
>   is a superficial mechanism that
>   requires the client implementation to
>   enforce the stored password. Because
>   the password itself is not used as a
>   key to the encoding and decoding
>   cipher algorithms, it does not provide
>   any security benefit to preventing the
>   PST data to be read by unauthorized
>   parties.
>
> Moreover, the password is stored as a
>   CRC-32 hash of the original password
>   string, which is prone to collisions
>   and is relatively weak against a
>   brute-force approach.

Microsoft say

> We recommend that you use Encrypting File System (EFS) or Windows
>   BitLocker Drive Encryption to help secure the data in a .pst file. The
>   Compressible Encryption and High Encryption options provide only a
>   basic level of security.

from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/829971

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia, man:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_Storage_Table)

> Microsoft (MS) offers three values for
>   the encryption setting: none,
>   compressible, and high. None
>   encryption is easy because the .pst
>   file contains data in plaintext, and a
>   simple text editor will show the
>   contents.
>
> Compressible encryption is a simple
>   byte-substitution cipher with a fixed
>   substitution table. Of course, since
>   the table is fixed, it is also widely
>   known. Attackers can simply decipher
>   the data and see the computer's
>   plaintext.
>
> High (sometimes called "better")
>   encryption is similar to a WWII German
>   Enigma cipher with three fixed rotors,
>   which are widely known. If the key,
>   which is the value of an internal
>   identifier, is known, attackers can
>   simply decipher the data and see the
>   computer's plaintext.

So, is this something you're trying to do for home use, or are you trying to rollout encryption to your users? Why specifically just to their PST files; what specific problem are you trying to solve?